# URL output from database

Tags: php, database, url

With this code:

```
if(empty($aItemInfo['url'])) {
    $url = '<p>&nbsp;</p>';
} else { 
    $url = ' | <a href="'.$aItemInfo['url'].'" target="_blank">LINK</a>';
}
```

I've got this as output:

> http://localhost/tester/www.google.com

In db there is only `www.google.com` and ofcourse it's fictional.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you seriously giving a link to `localhost` and asking us to magically hack into your computer to find out what it's doing?

Comment: why don't you add the protocol to avoid the assumption of the browser that the url given is a relative path, like this: `<a href="http://'.$aItemInfo['url'].'" target="_blank">LINK</a>'`

Comment: It's a relative vs absolute link problem; not him giving you localhost...

Comment: @Kolink That's an example of the output. Your comment is unnecessary.

Comment: @Kolink...-I believe you didn't get the point. For the rest, big THANKS.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `http://` while parsing your code, before using it in the `<a>` tag.

If all your URLs will be without `http://` use this code:

```
$url = 'http://'.$aItemInfo['url'];
```

Then use `$url`

Comment: Can't 'couse i've got IF condition where in one case i don't have anything on output and on other link.

Answer (score 3):

Not too sure what you're trying to link to. If you're linking to an external site you'll need to add http:// in front of the link. If not, the link will be added to the end of the current domain name as shown above

Answer (score 0):

You can put links are relative or absolute paths.  If you don't include the "http://" part, then it assumes that it is a relative path.  Add href="http://'.$aItemInfo['url'].'"